# Opening OSM files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am trying to import an OSM file of a State Park that was added in OpenStreetMap into QGIS, and it seems no matter what I do, I just cannot get it to work.

I've installed a bunch of plugins, etc, but nothing.

Comment: did you mean that you're trying to import an 'OSM file of a State Park'?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and why?  It would help to know what "bunch of plugins" were unhelpful to you.

Comment: About "import a shapefile of a State Park that was done in OpenStreetMap" > How did you get this shapefile? From a download? If yes from where? From a conversion? If yes, how did you do it? We can't help if you don't provide enough details in your question.

Comment: I simply went to Open Street Map, and put the name of the park in the search window.  I picked the map that looked the best, and saved it as an osm file.  I then tried to drag and drop that file into QGIS, and could not get it to open.  I'm new to using QGIS, as I said, so I'm afraid I don't have a lot of other information for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL/OGR can read OSM format and in theory it is possible to open OSM files directly with QGIS (don't forget to switch to All files, I've just tried in QGIS 2.12 on Ubuntu and it works, but my QGIS is compiled with GDAL 2.0). QGIS will ask you to select type of features. However in practice I found it not always working (OSGeo4W QGIS couldn't open it in my case). You can try.

If it doesn't work you can go this route:

1. Go to http://overpass-turbo.eu
2. Navigate to an area where your park is
3. Type in a query:

   `way
     [leisure=park]
     ({{bbox}});
     (._;>;);
   out;`
4. Hit Run
5. Export result as GeoJSON
6. Open in QGIS

[Working example for a State park](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/cnI)

Comment: this worked perfectly