# Cannot open .osm file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, import

I want to view a `.osm` file that was generated from an Overpass API query.

I tried the steps given in [QGIS tutorial](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QGIS_tutorial) on OSM wiki. The tutorial says

> 1. Start QGIS Desktop
> 2. Go to: Vector (menu) → OpenStreetMap → Import Topology from XML.
> 3. Select the .osm file, and it'll suggest a name for the SpatiaLite database that will be created from this data.

But when I opened the QGIS, the vector menu does not give drop-down submenu.

Am I missing something in the steps or the QGIS tool on my machine is not installed correctly? Any suggestions?

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168540/opening-osm-files-in-qgis) is the most related question I could find. But it was not very helpful when it comes to my problem.

Comment: Are you using QGIS 3.4?

Comment: Check this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305895/qgis-training-manual-vector-menu/305901#305901

Comment: @ahmadhanb I'm using 3.0.3-Girona. that link is helpful. thans.

Comment: @ahmadhanb Can I do these steps in this version of QGIS. 
Do I install the osm-plugin to get the submenues under Vector. As currently Vector menu shows nothing under it

Comment: I didn’t test osm-plugin before so it’s a good chance to try it. I think no problem to use the plugin in QGIS 3.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

You can load OSM data saved on your local disc into QGIS with `Add Vector layer`.

Alternatively, use the `QuickOSM` plugin. You can run your Overpass queries directly here, and load an osm file you saved to disk. Or load everything inside the canvas with the `OpenStreetMap - All OSM` query in the `My Queries` tab.

BTW you should update to QGIS 3.4, because 3.0 had lots of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know that the *Vector* menu has no any content, is having the *Processing* plugin unticked. Check it:

[image: processing-plugin]